# Navigation Component deeplink cuts of query parameter when query value is also a url with query parameters

Tags: java, android, kotlin, deep-linking

There is this deeplink:

```
https://example.com/?url=https://google.com/?search=apple&sourceid=chrome
```

deeplink is then parsed to:

```
domain = https://example.com
queryParams = {
    url = https://google.com/?search=apple
    sourceid = chrome
}
```

whereas I want it to be parsed like this:

```
domain = https://example.com
queryParams = {
    url= https://google.com/?search=apple&sourceid=chrome
}
```

Comment: That's not a parseable Uri - query parameters need to be [URL encoded](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_encoding).